# CSS * wildcard on a responsive situation

Tags: css

on my site, my main CSS stylesheet has thi attr:

```
* {
     margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 15px; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
```

But when viewed using a mobile phone, it's not suitable. I have tried doing this

```
* {
     margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 15px; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    * {
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    }
  }
```

To deactivate the * selector when the width is 800px but It does not work. Can you help me guys?

Comment: Don't set the font to each element with the *. Set it only to the html or body node. It will be inherited. In the media-query you assign the property/value again - that makes no difference. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because the media query is written wrong you did not change anything in the media query.
You should add new css rules to the media query. add the rules you want for 800px width in the media query

```
@media screen AND (max-width: 800px) {
    * {
        margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto; 
    padding: 2px; 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    }
  }
```

add your desired values.